# How to solve $|4x+1|+|4-x|=x+19$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I need some help solving the equation $|4x+1|+|4-x|= x+19$.

I know I have to divide it into different cases. I thought I had two cases.

First case: $4x+1 = -2x-15$. The first case is correct, and I get the correct solution.

However, the second case I thought of was: $4x+1 = 2x+15$. However, this gives me $x=7$, which is the incorrect solution. I am not quite sure how to find the other solution.

I tried googling it, but mostly it only shows examples of equations using just one absolute value expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can have $4$ cases for two absolute values

1. $+\mid+$
2. $+ \mid -$
3. $- \mid +$
4. $- \mid -$

- First case is when $x \ge -1/4$ and $x \le 4$.
- Second case is when $x \ge -1/4$ and $x > 4$.
- Third case is when $x < -1/4$ and $x \le 4$.
- Fourth case is when $x < -1/4$ and $x > 4$.

Consider each case, as you have tried in your attempt. After finishing each case, you should check if the root you found belongs to the range of that case.

Comment: Oh, so I get like four different solutions, but then I actually need to plug it into the original equation and verify which one are correct and which I can discard.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative purely arithmetic method, if you don't want to discuss all the inequalities, is to use variables for the signs.

$a(4x+1)+b(4-x)=x+19\iff x=\dfrac{19-a-4b}{4a-b-1}\ $ for $\ a,b\in \{-1,+1\}$

You get $4$ possible values and plugging them eliminates two of them.

Comment: This assumes that $a$ and $b$ are independent, which they may no be in general.

Comment: @lhf I completely agree, this is why it delivers spurious solutions (for instance here -1,-1 is not possible), but it won't omit any. Therefore the true solutions are among them and the verification step (plugging obtained values to see if they work) is part of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "critical-points" method, which is more efficient than taking cases (in general, there are $2^m$ separate cases, where $m$ is the number of absolute-value terms).
$$|4x+1|+|4-x|= x+19$$

Let $f(x)=|4x+1|+|4-x|- x-19.$

|  | $x<-\frac14$ | $-\frac14<x<4$ | $x>4$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(x)$ | $-6x-16$ | $2x-14$ | $4x-22$ |
| $f(x)=0$ | $x=-\frac83$ | $$x=7\\\text{(contradiction; rejected)}$$ | $x=\frac{11}2$ |

Answer (score 0):

$$ 1) \begin {cases} x< -\frac {1} {4} \\-4x-1+4-x=x+19 \end {cases}$$

$$ 2) \begin {cases} -\frac {1} {4} \le x<4 \\4x+1+4-x=x+19 \end {cases}$$

$$ 3) \begin {cases} x \ge 4 \\ 4x+1+x-4=x+19 \end {cases}$$